# Spring Cloud Gateway - RewriteLocationResponseHeader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have the following route inside my Spring Cloud Gateway configuration:

```
- id: pgadmin
  uri: lb://pg-admin-service
  predicates:
  - Path=/pgadmin/**
  filters:
  - RewritePath=/pgadmin(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
  - RewriteLocationResponseHeader=AS_IN_REQUEST, Location, ,    <---- this line is incorrect
```

The request comes in on `http://10.0.0.100/pgadmin/` as an unauthenticated user. The application returns a response containing a location header with the value:

`http://10.0.0.100/login`

The browser tries to rediect to that URL. Instead, it should redirect to:

`http://10.0.0.100/pgadmin/login`

What is the correct value for the `RewriteLocationResponseHeader` in the route definition?

Many thanks

JT

Comment: try just  `- RewriteLocationResponseHeader`

Comment: Hi if you have found a hack to this please provide the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AnjanKrishna I posted what worked for us below. If it works can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try something this if you want to rewrite your path:

```
- id: docs
  uri: lb://auth-service
  predicates:
  - Path=/my-auth/**
  filters:
  - RewritePath=/my-auth(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
```

or to simply forward the request onto your service:

```
- id: docs
  uri: lb://auth-service
  predicates:
  - Path=/my-auth/**
```